# How can I check if Zend_Form_Elements has no decorators set

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I find that even if I just declare an element like

```
$this->addElement('textarea', 'txt1');
```

I find that it already has decorators set

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getElement('txt1')->getDecorators());
```

http://pastebin.com/7Y24g62w

I want to test that I didn't set decorators using setDecorators() or using something like

```
$this->addElement('textarea', 'txt1', array(
    'decorators' => array(...)
));
```

If I didn't set any decorators then apply default decorators, how can I do that. I want to apply default decorators per element basis, not using `Zend_Form#setDisableLoadDefaultDecoraotrs()`

Comment: When you don't assign decorators yourself, the default ones are loaded. Do you want to test wheter the default decorators are loaded,  you loaded some decorators yourself or if the complete stack of decorators is emptyy?

Comment: I want to test that I did not explicitly set any decorators, so I think that will be whether defaults are loaded or they are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, depending on how exactly you want to be sure a decorator hasn't been changed.

**Decorator without option**

If you just want to know if all default decorators are set, without thinking about the options of each decorator, you can use this option. Of course you can alter options of a default decorator and this method won't recognize this (but it is faster than an extensive check). Unfortunately the default decorators are hard-coded in the `Zend_Form_Element` at `Zend_Form_Element::loadDefaultDecorators()` so you need to copy that list. When in future releases the chain changes, you need to alter your code.

```
<?php
$default    = array(
    'Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper',
    'Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors',
    'Zend_Form_Decorator_Description',
    'Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag',
    'Zend_Form_Decorator_Label',
);
$decorators = array_keys($element->getDecorators());
if ($decorators === $default) {
    // They are the same
}
```

**Check decorators with all options**

Here you create a copy of your element and at this copy you reload all default decorators. They get instantiated again so it takes a bit more resources, but all options of the decorators are checked as well.

```
$clone = clone $element;
$clone->clearDecorators()
      ->setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators(false)
      ->loadDefaultDecorators();
if ($clone === $element) {
    // They are the same
}
```